# How to allow only numbers, dots and signals?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've this class to force only numbers characters

```
public class BsnValidationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    private string _prevValue = string.Empty;

    protected override void Invoke(Entry entry)
    {
        int n;
        var isNumeric = int.TryParse(entry.Text, out n);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.Text) && (entry.Text.Length > 9 || !isNumeric))
        {
            entry.Text = _prevValue;
            return;
        }

        _prevValue = entry.Text;
    }
}
```

but now I need to know how can I implement this to only allow numbers, signals (- exactly) and dots... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `decimal.TryParse` method.

```
var isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(entry.Text, out n);
```

Furthermore, you don't need the extra check

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.Text)
```

If the value of `entry.Text` is such the the above function returns `true`, then `decimal.TryParse` would return false for such a value.

That being said, your class can be refactored as below:

```
public class BsnValidationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    private string _prevValue = string.Empty;

    protected override void Invoke(Entry entry)
    {
        decimal n;
        var isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(entry.Text, out n);

        _prevValue = isDecimal ? entry.Text : _prevValue; 
   }
}
```

**Update**

There is an overload of `TryParse` method that takes as arguments also the [style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) of the number and a [format provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    out decimal result
)
```

You could find examples on how to use it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: but this method would cover the signal part?

Comment: It would cover it.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me!! But instead of dot is the comma which is allowed... This can be a problem since C# treat decimal numbers with a dot, right?

Comment: @IgorHenriques no, it depend on your current CultureInfo

Comment: btw, if you on C# 7.0, you can use inline out parameter declaration: `if (decimal.TryParse(entry.Text, out var n)) _prevValue = entry.Text;`